# android 4.1.2 apps shortcut disapperead from home screen

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I am using Huawei phone with android 4.1.2. Currently I'm losing the app shortcut on my home screen after a crash of the system recently. During the crash, I dragged the Whatsapp and Hoiio apps shortcut to the bottom menu (phone shortcut, browser and messaging by default). After a while, the phone turned off due to battery dry. But after I restarted the phone, the shortcut for the apps disappeared, although the apps are still installed (as shown in Google Play Store). After a few times of re-installation of the apps, the apps shortcut keep disappearing from the home scree. This android does not have applications page, only home page. How can I fix this and make sure that my apps shortcut can remain on the home screen?

Answer (score 1):

I found fix for this, just visit [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61336822) and dowload the file "**fixdatatoggle.apk**",   install it and enjoy. It will show your missing mobile data icon in quick setting panel notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. **Resetting your current launcher:**
   Note that all your personalization concerning your homescreens will be deleted this way. I assume something got messed up in its configuration, so by resetting its cache/data we make it a "virgin" again for a fresh start.

   - Go to *Settings→Apps*
   - Select the "All" tab
   - Look for your Laucher (Homescreen) app
   - Open its entry, and push the buttons to "clear cache" and "delete data"
2. **Install an alternative launcher:**
   If you're hesistant to "virginize" your pre-configured launcher, you might want to try an alternative launcher first. Simply pick any from the Playstore, good choices include [Apex Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apex-launcher/com.anddoes.launcher) and [Nova Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nova-launcher/com.teslacoilsw.launcher). See if your problem exists with them as well. If you don't like any of those, you can simply remove them and automatically have back your "old one".

My guess is, going with the second variant you will forget about your current launcher, while at the same time your problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solve it by simply moving the application (that lost its icon) from the SD Card to the main memory.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Many Android launchers load before the SD card is mounted and automatic throw away shortcuts that can't be "reached".

Answer (score 0):

lenovo mobile phone ..tap settings-common-add-applications.
Make sure you have space on your main screen or move to other screen