# Home-screen shortcuts disappear after reboot

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

In my Lenovo A2107a the shortcuts of the applications that they are running from the sd card or the onboard "USB" memory partition, they disappear after rebooting. How can I set of fix that?
The applications were moved via Android's interface and not by another app.
Android 4 ics.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question and add how you moved those apps to SD: App2SD? Link2SD? That might make a difference, as the latter completely moves apps over, and sdcards are usually mounted *after* the `boot_completed` event (so the homescreen app might check for them too early). (I'm not sure about this as I never used Link2SD; but still, that information might be useful for those who know).

Comment: Related: [Can I prevent home screen shortcuts from getting deleted or moved around?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38297) and [android 4.1.2 apps shortcut disapperead from home screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54228)

Comment: @AlEverett don't see how the first one is related, personally. OP: does this happen for all apps installed on the SD Card, or just some?